# How to use dropdownlist with checkbox list control in gridview

Tags: asp.net

Suppose there is a `grid-view` and i want to use `dropdownlist` control with `checklist boxes` in  `grid-view`. 
How to use it ? Can anybody help me ?

Comment: You want to show checkboxes inside the dropdownlist itself as choices. No, it is not possible without weird hacks. It would be better to use `multiple=multiple` attribute to allow multi-select.

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget this plugion mught work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it will work but you need to have **AjaxToolkit**

**CSS**

```
  <style>
    .PnlDesign
        {
            border: solid 1px #000000;
            height: 150px;
            width: 330px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
            background-color: #EAEAEA;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        .txtbox
        {
            background-image: url(../images/drpdwn.png);
            background-position: right top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            cursor: pointer;
            cursor: hand;
        }
        </style>
```

**ASPX**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="274px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" Text="Select Customers" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox"
                    Height="20px" Width="322px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Panel ID="PnlCust" runat="server" CssClass="PnlDesign">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer One</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer Two</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer Three</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer Four</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer Five</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer Six</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Customer Seven</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PceSelectCustomer" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCustomer"
                    PopupControlID="PnlCust" Position="Bottom">
                </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to use `DataList` instead of using `GridView`, in `DataList` you can use `<ItemTemplate>` to get your desired formatted output, you can put images, controls as you want.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil. I ll try in DataList.